# Left margin is not working from java

Tags: android

I am adding an image and giving margin from left using below code.

```
layoutParams.setMargins(translateBy, 0, 0, marginBottom);
slideIcon.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

This code is working for all devices of different density and size.

But this is not working for device with properties :-
540x960, 240dpi, 4.7 inch device

But if we give the margin from .xml file then its working.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

Comment: @Stanojkovic Good Logic.

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya Thanks.

Comment: @SanniRaj Move ahead .

Answer (score 3):

You can use **DisplayMetrics** Logic

> A structure describing general information about a display, such as
>   its size, density, and font scaling.

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

       int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
       int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

     layoutParams.setMargins(DeviceTotalWidth/8, 0, 0, marginBottom); // left, top, right, bottom
      // DeviceTotalWidth/8 set yours left margin
```

**Edited**

@Courtesy goes to  #**Stanojkovic**

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ); params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Hope this helps .